MapView Callout onPress does not fire on iOS
Why does the Callout inside a MapView not fire the onPress event?  I have tried not using the Callout's onPress prop & instead use a Pressable as either a parent or chile of the Callout with no difference.
<ClusterMap
        clusterColor={colors.main.default}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_REGION}
        ref={mapRef}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill]}
      >
        {data?.map((datum, i) => {
          const { location } = datum.location.geometry;
          return (
            <Marker
              coordinate={{ latitude: location.lat, longitude: location.lng }}
              identifier={datum.id}
              key={datum.id}
              onPress={() => handleClickedMarker(i)}
            >
              {clickedMarker === i && (
                <Callout
                  onPress={() => handlePress(datum.id)}
                  style={{
                    zIndex: 500, // doesn't make a difference
                    position: 'absolute',  // doesn't make a difference
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  }}
                >
                  <View>
                    <Typography h3 h3Style={{ fontSize: 16 }} numberOfLines={1}>
                      {datum.locationName}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography>
                      {new Date(datum.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                    </Typography>
                  </View>
                  <Pressable
                    onPress={() => handlePress(datum.id)}
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      marginLeft: 4,
                    }}
                  >
                    <GoButtonIcon color={colors.main.default} />
                  </Pressable>
                </Callout>
              )}
              <MapPinIcon color={colors.main.default} height="40" width="40" />
            </Marker>
          );
        })}
      </ClusterMap>

I have seen other suggestions on line, but none of them are valid it seems.
